# method does not override or implement a method from a supertype Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have the following code: https://pastebin.com/19NJjj9S (I put it here because it's too much code for stackoverflow)

But it doesn't overwrite the onClick method (line 192) and I don't understand why.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.txtViewNewAnimalNacimiento:
                showDatePickerDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.machoOHembra:
                sexo = elegirSexo(v);
        }
    }
```

The idea behind the override the onclick method is to get a date and receive a radiogroup to set one of the values.
If anyone can help me, I will apreciate it.

Comment: your activity needs to also implement `View.OnClickListener` to be able to override onClick

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

implements View.OnClickListener on your activity

and for radioButton.setOnClickListener(this)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that